# How to get the collection of "instock" products through Resource Model in Magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

Is it possible to fetch the collection of "in stock" products through resource model in Magento  ?

I have tried this code

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('is_in_stock', 0);
```

But it is throwing Fatal error

Answer (score 1):

try below code

```
$productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->addInStockFilterToCollection($productCollection);
echo "<pre>";print_r($productCollection->getData());
```

// use addInStockFilterToCollection()

Answer (score 1):

Just add at the end of product collection code

Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->addInStockFilterToCollection($productCollection);