# Adding filter in Magento

Tags: php, magento

How to add this filter to this code??
 =================================================================

```
$category_model = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(55); 
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection'); 
$collection->addCategoryFilter($category_model);
```

---

I want to show only products in stock, how to do this with following code Magento

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it works for you [In Stock Product Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22276027/how-to-get-the-collection-of-instock-products-through-resource-model-in-magent)?

Code from answer:

```
$category_model = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(55); 
$productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
$productCollection->addCategoryFilter($category_model);
Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')
    ->addInStockFilterToCollection($productCollection);
echo "<pre>";print_r($productCollection->getData());
```

Comment: can you give me all section? witch this $category_model = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(55); $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection'); $collection->addCategoryFilter($category_model);